# Mercurial remotes on the file system instead of http server

Tags: windows, mercurial, ntfs

I'm currently working on a migration from svn to mercurial. My needs are plain and simple, I need source control over an intranet in our company. I see examples everywhere for setupping remote repos over IIS. I just don't see the point when I can just make a share on a server.

Can I still setup authorizations and authentications on repos using NTFS permissions?

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a repository on a file share works, but it's not the way recommended by the Mercurial team.

See the "shared disk" part of [Publishing Repositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Choosing_a_publishing_method) on the HG wiki:

> generally restricted to intranets, **not generally recommended** due to general issues with network filesystem reliability

Be sure to check out [Chris Becke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812522/mercurial-remotes-on-the-file-system-instead-of-http-server/7813449#7813449) as well, because he points out another valid disadvantage (people with write access deleting stuff from the network share, be it intentionally or not).

If you are aware of (and can live with) these things, putting the repositories on the network share is without a doubt the easiest way to setup.

My personal experience is that it works perfectly as long as the Windows share is on a "real" Windows machine.
At work we're using a share on a real Windows server without problems, but at home I ran into issues with a NAS (which behaves like a Windows share but actually runs on Linux).
You can read more about my experiences here:
[Can you 'push' to network share using Mercurial on 64bit Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250031/can-you-push-to-network-share-using-mercurial-on-64bit-windows-7/6484300#6484300)

Comment: The main problem is if you lose network connectivity, or if the server/share has locking issues (like with that NAS), then if something happens midway of a push, there's no cleanup step. There's no guarantee that the repository is still valid. There's of course no 100% guarantee locally, or with a server either, but the chance of it being OK goes way way up when something goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, I know. We never had problems with that at work yet (after using HG for nearly two years now), but I know that it could happen any time. The problem is, all the other ways to host a repository seem to be complicated to set up and I never had the time to wrap my head around it, whereas putting the repositories on a network share is easy and **just works** (yes, there *may* be some problems later, but at first it just works!). Unfortunately we have to do the hosting ourselves at work (for my private projects I'm using Bitbucket now, but at work hosting our code externally is not an option).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reasons to prefer, well, anything at all to a writable file share.

In essence it comes down to, there is a limited amount of damage someone can do with the ability to do a push via a web-method.
A read/write share on the other hand is necessary to do a push, but also allows a user to delete an entire repo, history and all.

Without even invoking malicious intent, people (or rogue software agents) have been know to navigate to random network shares and accidentally drag a file to someplace it doesn't belong.

The best reason to lock your PC is not because your co-workers find it amusing to use an unlocked email account to send porn to HR, but because its amazing what a cleaning lady can do with a rag and a keyboard. Its also amazing what Music Library applications can find while scanning all shares in a workgroup, and carefully "move" and catalog to someones Library.

Comment: What if I enforce permissions to deny any delete of the root folder and .hg/*? Also, only the dev group will be allowed to read/write on the repositories. The remote repo would also be backed-up by every local repo + real backup. So, I don't really see a big problem here..

Comment: You're right, the chance for manipulation is small when only the devs have access to the share at all. We're doing it like this as well and it works. But even if the devs are all technical people and know what they're doing: the chance of somebody accidentally dragging a folder to somewhere else always **does** exist, as Chris pointed out in his answer.