# Hg TortoiseHg commit error on Windows 7

Tags: mercurial, commit, tortoisehg

I clone a new repository by TortoiseHg version 2.1.3. Then do some change. When I do commit, I get this message as below.

My desktop drive mapping is connected to Linux server by Samba.

I am so appreciate if someone can help.

```
% hg commit --repository V:\htdocs\critical\mysite2 --verbose --user MyUser --message=testing Mercuial  V:\htdocs\critical\mysite2/application/controllers/package.php
smartdox/application/controllers/package.php
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
[command returned code 255 Fri Jan 13 14:30:17 2012]
mysite2%
```

Comment: Did you try to clone the repository to a local drive on Windows 7, committing to it and then pushing to the Linux "drive"? I use this scenario on a VirtualBox with Windows 7 and a Ubuntu 11.10 as a host (shared folder, not Samba), and it works well.

Answer (score 13):

For me changing the setting:

```
Global Settings -> TortoiseHg -> Monitor Repo Changes
```

to

```
localonly
```

helped.

The long discussion in the official bug tracker: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/889/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed to solve my (same) problem!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this same problem, but I've noticed that "occasionally" I am able to commit changes.  I think the 'another process' is something on the server.

When I fail to commit, hg gives an error saying (among other things) "transaction abort! rollback failed - please run hg recover".

If I run hg recover, sometimes that fails, too (in use by another process).  If I wait a minute or two, then retry to recover, it often succeeds.

Once the recovery succeeds, if I wait another minute or two, then the commit often succeeds when I retry it.

My theory is that the server is indexing or virus-scanning the contents of .hg/

---

I don't know a guaranteed work-around, but on my small repository I can often get my changesets in if I give it a try or two.  Your luck is likely to increase as the activity on your repository files decreases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about **committing**, but I know that Mercurial/TortoiseHG has issues when you **push** to a Linux drive which is mapped under Windows.

See these answers I wrote about it:

- [Mercurial remotes on the file system instead of http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812522/mercurial-remotes-on-the-file-system-instead-of-http-server/7814554#7814554)
- [Can you 'push' to network share using Mercurial on 64bit Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250031/can-you-push-to-network-share-using-mercurial-on-64bit-windows-7/6484300#6484300)

Maybe the same problems occur when the repository you're trying to commit to directly resides on a mapped Linux drive.

I'd suggest that you put the repository on a real Windows drive and try if you can commit there.
If yes, the problems you described are probably because of the Linux drive.