# mercurial repo on windows share accessing from ubuntu - permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, file-permissions, cifs

i just copied an existing mercurial repository to a Folder on a NAS. 
I can copy, create, delete files in that folder without any problems but when i try to push to that repository i got a "permission denied" error.

I'm using an xubuntu box with the following fstab entry to connect to the NAS:

```
//192.168.0.32/X /mnt/X cifs exec,user=USERNAME,pass=PASSWORD,auto,umask=002,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777    0       1
```

It doesn't matter if i'm root or logged in as a user. I have 777 rights in all folders.

If i make a push it looks like this ( sorry for the german ;) )

```
hg push
Übertrage nach /mnt/X/xxx/
Suche nach Änderungen
Füge Änderungssätze hinzu
Abbruch: Permission denied: /mnt/X/xxx/.hg/store/.00changelog.i-fh60CC
```

If i try a hg status it tooks a while and then this

```
hg status
Abbruch: Permission denied: /mnt/X/xxx/.hg/.dirstate-TcgoRN
```

I have absolutely no idea how to get this working since i can do anything with the files as long as i'm not trying to push to the repo. Actually i can go into that folder and change or delete the exact same file that is mentioned above. 
The idea is to use the NAS as a shared repo solution for a group of developers. My co-worker uses a windows 7 box. He can push without problems. So maybe the fstab entries are wrong.

Thanks for everyone who tries to help.

Comment: What is the NAS running?

Comment: It is a standalone NAS. I'm not completely sure what OS is the NAS running but it shares with smb.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using a similar setup, just the other way round (Windows 7 and XP machines trying to push to a repository on a NAS running on Linux):
[Can you 'push' to network share using Mercurial on 64bit Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484300/6884)

I don't know if your issue is *really* the same, but at least it sounds familiar ("Permission denied").

In general, putting repositories on a network share is possible, but not the way recommended by the Mercurial team.
Quote from [Publishing Mercurial Repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Choosing_a_publishing_method) on the Mercurial wiki:

> shared disk: [...] generally restricted to intranets, **not generally recommended** due to general issues with network filesystem reliability

Comment: Yeah, i know that security and network shares won't fit together but we only use it for our local intranet behind a netgear firewall.

Comment: Actually we had it working the other way round. The share was on my ubuntu box and shares the folder with samba. Most of the time that worked like a charm but my PC has to stay on with this setup for the whole time. We have relatively free working time so there are times when i'm not at the office but others want to push and share their stuff.

Comment: The problem is not security. At work, we are using HG repositories on a network share as well, but this is all Windows (servers and client machines) and we didn't experience any problems so far (in over two years). Apparently, the problems only occur in mixed Windows/Linux environments.