# hg push fails with error code 255 and error message file exists

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to push some changes in mercurial that involve pushing a new branch but I get this output:

> searching for changes
>
> adding changesets
>
> adding manifests
>
> adding file changes
>
> transaction abort!
>
> rollback completed
>
> abort: file exists

I'm using Mercurial 1.9.2 with sub repos the command I'm using is `hg push --new-branch`. I also tried `-f`, nothing seems to work.
I'm pushing from Linux machine (ununtu 10.4) to Windows machine. The Windows is mounted using cifs mount...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, it appears that some files attributes have been change.
changing them back to default solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of remote repository are you pushing to?

I had a similar problem (but with a different error message, though) when pushing from a Windows machine to a network share on my NAS at home, which runs on Linux:
[Can you 'push' to network share using Mercurial on 64bit Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250031/can-you-push-to-network-share-using-mercurial-on-64bit-windows-7)

Pushing from a Windows machine to a network share on a Windows machine works (we are doing this at work), even though pushing to network shares is not recommended by the Mercurial team.

Quote from [the "shared disk" part at "Publishing Repositories" in the Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Choosing_a_publishing_method).

> generally restricted to intranets, **not generally recommended** due to general issues with network filesystem reliability

Comment: I'm pushing from Linux machine (ununtu 10.4) to Windows machine.
The Windows is mounted using cifs mount...