# Free source control tool to replace CVS - separate repository /working folders are required

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, cvs

I've worked with CVS for many years and would be glad to move on to more advanced tools.

Are there any source control tools that allow to keep the working directory and repository in separate directories as in good ol' days?

While this request seem to be out-fashioned today, keeping the repository in a separate location mainly allows flexible backup/restore plans for repos and user files (including dropbox, etc.).

I prefer to avoid using 24/7 external/local VCS servers. I'm not interested in commercial tools either.

Is there a way to configure git/mercurial to use ***separate*** local folders for the repository and the project? Or am I stuck with CVS/SVN?

Thanks
Alex

---

```
Edit
```

I see from some comments that the VCS server idea is imperative to some of the users. This is not what I am looking for. For those that are in hurry to point to the fact that cvs requires servers - this is not true. The cvs repository can be stored on a corporate network storage, eliminating the need for the server side. I assume SVN to be the same. The reason for this is simple - network shares are cheaper/easier to operate than a dedicated 24/7/365 server.

---

```
Answer (with robert's help):
```

Looks like there is an easy workaround for the lack of the central local repository in Git/Mercurial. The trick is to clone/push/pull the local repository to a dedicated local/shared repository which can be used as the central one.

While it is not very effective storage-wise, this seems to be a reasonable compromise for all the included benefits of Git/Mercurial tools.

Thanks

Comment: You mean like with any VCS that supports the concept of "server" (be it an external process or just a directory somewhere)? I think virtually every serious VCS supports that.

Comment: "I prefer to avoid using 24/7 external/local web/non-web based source control servers."  What does that mean?  Do you claim CVS and Subversion meet this requirement?

Comment: @Alex I was referring to the fact that you seemed to prohibit both "web" and "non-web" options in your question.  That combination rules out most options I can think of.

Comment: @Alex your current solution uses network shares.  Why does this mean your new solution must use network shares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question indicates you should have no problems having a central Mercurial repository on a network share, given certain limitations: [Can you 'push' to network share using Mercurial on 64bit Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250031/can-you-push-to-network-share-using-mercurial-on-64bit-windows-7)

However, individual users will still have local copies of the repository.

Before ruling out non-shared folder methods, you should review Mercurial's page on [publishing repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories).  Also, look about halfway down on [this Git page](http://git-scm.com/about) (specifically, the "Distributed" section).  What you want should work with both Mercurial and Git, but it's not how people tend to use these version control systems.

Comment: Finally found how to mark accepted answers :) Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Both git and mercurial allow you to use folders as repository. You can share that folders (using what you wish: Samba, Windows Sharing, Drop-box) and use them as repos in other locations. See:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS

Also, see what is `bare` repository:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html

Comment: I was trying to avoid multiple copies of the main repository, but it looks like this  would not fit the original ideas that led to the creation of Git/Mercurial

Comment: Multiple copies are NOT a problem, no need to avoid it.