# Is there a real advantage using a web server for Mercurial repositories?

Tags: mercurial

I am a remote worker and I have VPN access to a Windows file server share. It seems that everywhere I read that the recommendation is to use a Web server based repository.  It would be a tough sell for me because I don't know the real advantages to weigh against the cost of maintaining a web server whether it is a Windows or Linux based.

There would only be two people accessing it at this time and neither would need access outside the VPN or the main office. Someday maybe more. but not in the foresable future.

Comment: Use a 3rd-party provider. This makes it so *you* don't have to do the work to setup/run the server or worry about backups or upgrades or availability or .. (plus, you get the pretty web tools) .. BitBucket (for instance, because this is what I have used) has unlimited private repositories for free (but only accessible for 5 users under the free plan); the plans are affordable, I think, but there are likely other (cheaper?) Hg hosts too.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a Mercurial server? I have, and I promise you, using a 3rd party service is way, _way_ easier to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add my 2 cents as well - the [PublishingRepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories) page linked by Martin says the following about server shares:

> generally restricted to intranets, **not generally recommended** due to general issues with network filesystem reliability

From my own experience, putting HG repositories on server shares works on Windows as long as the clients **and** the server are Windows machines.

I had problems at home with [Windows clients trying to access HG repositories on a NAS running on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484300/6884).

At work, we used HG repositories on a share on a "real" Windows server for over 3 years without a single problem.
In the meantime, we switched to [hgweb](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb) - I had to move to a new server anyway, so I decided to give hgweb a shot and managed to get it to run on the new server, mainly with [this tutorial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebInIisOnWindows).

I can confirm that hgweb seems to be faster (like Eldad already said) and I agree with Martin's statement about being able to view history in a browser.

However, both these advantages are nice, but I could live without them.
If the shared drive works for you, just keep it.
IMO, Installing hgweb is not as easy as Eldad says in his answer *(at least it wasn't that easy for me on a Windows server. On the other hand, I know absolutely nothing about web servers and IIS...maybe it would have been easier with that knowledge)*.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it is what I really wanted to know. I had to ask a question in a way that wasn't totaly open ended so it could stay open. I may need to make my own answer to truely answer the question as asked. (1) Solution when not everyone is on the same intranet. (2) Solution when users are working in a mixed environment. (3) Solution when shares may not be a true Windows  share. (4) History available in a browser (5) More efficent data transfer (faster)

Answer (score 1):

Putting a repository on a network share and pushing/pulling to/from it is supported by Mercurial.

When people advice you to access the repository using a webserver (such as `hg serve` for short-term serving or the [CGI/WSGI script](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) for long-term serving), it's probably because of

- Potential for bugs in network file system drivers/software. Mercurial uses hardlinks internally to make clones efficient, and there has been problems with remote filesystems reporting the hardlink count incorrectly, see [bug 761](http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=761) and [bug 1866](http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1866).

  These bugs were fixed more than two years ago in version 1.6.3 and 1.7.1, respectively. Many people have used repositories stored on network drives before and after these bugs were fixed.
- The ability to browse the history in your browser, which can be convenient when you want to point a coworker to something in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what @Martin wrote.

I have a duplicate setup. A network share and also a web server over the shared repositories. I find that the web is **faster**. This is especially good for remote connections (as in your case).

The web server setup is very simple and easy.

I hope this helps.