# Using SourceTree or Mercurial in LAN

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to make the version control repository and use it within a local network using SourceTree or Mercurial. Didn't find any relevant info for this. Is it at all possible to use only lan for this?

Comment: Of course it is, D in DVCS stands for "distributed".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using it in a local network instead of the Internet is possible as well.

You need some kind of server - there are plenty of possibilities, see [Publishing Mercurial Repositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories) for an exhaustive list.

From personal experience, I know only two of the non-internet options listed there:

- network share ("shared disk" in the list) used at work for about three years without problems
- [hgweb](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb), Mercurial's default web interface ([looks like this](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo))

I wrote some more about my "Mercurial hosting experience" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407425/6884).