# Mercurial Permissions when using NAS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mercurial, nas

I have a Mercurial repository that is located on a NAS (Buffalo TeraStation).  It is mounted on a Ubuntu machine and is mapped onto a Windows 7 machine.

I have previously been able to clone, update, etc. from both the Linux machine and the Windows machine, but now am having problems.   Too many changes have been made (updating versions of hg, thg, etc.) to identify a specific point where things started to fail.

I can read and write files from both machines from/to the NAS.   I can use "cp" to copy entire repositories, but if I attempt to clone using hg (or thg) it fails.

When cloning an existing (in the NAS) repository to the Ubuntu machine, all of the files copy over, but the operation is aborted with the message:

```
abort: Operation not permitted:   (repository_path)/.hg/store/.phaseroots-94sdvj
[command returned code 255 Thu Jul 30 17:39:45 2015
```

When cloning an exiting (in the NAS) repository to the Windows machine, the cloning hangs (with no files transferred).

I have tried various [trusted] settings to no avail.
I have tried performing the hg clone command manually and it works properly when done with "sudo".   However, the cloned repository then is owned by "root".

I'm pretty sure this is a permissions problem, but have run out of ideas.  Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One thing can think of is support for hardlinks on the NAS you are using. 
For example some of the versions of Mercurial had problems with windows shares. For more information [here](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HardlinkedClones).

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation for the problem on the Linux machine, but the problems on the Windows machine might be caused by this exact setup (cloning from a Linux drive to a Windows machine).

Years ago, [I had similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484300/6884) *(although with different error messages)* when pushing from my Windows machine to repositories on a shared (Linux) NAS drive - see the link for more details.

But that was over five years ago and I didn't try it anymore since then, though.